# Como exibir no browser e de maneira amigável informações de um arquivo JSON?

Tags: php, json, display

A aplicação recebe um arquivo JSON, já validado, e deve exibi-lo para o usuário que é um programador.

Eu gostaria de exibir o JSON como nesse site de validação e beautify [JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Então eu queria que esse JSON:

```
{"glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"}}}}
}
```

Fosse exibido da maneira abaixo para que ficasse mais legível para o programador, assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que existe a possibilidade de expandir ou não o nodo.

Algém conhece alguma aplicação que faça isso?

Nota: Estou usando php.

Comment: No Laravel tem um método auxiliar dd() que exibe JSON no tela indentado, tenta dar uma olhada no código, acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: @zwitterion tem que ser em `json`? Se for `array` tenho uma alternativa. Se quiser posso postar uma resposta

Comment: Oi @DjalmaManfrin sim so pode ser um JSON. Mas se vc quiser posta ai o codigo para a array. Talvez alguem precise ou mesmo eu em um outro cenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instale via *composer* o pacote [var-dumper](https://github.com/rdehnhardt/var-dumper).

adicione a linha:

```
dd(json_decode($seu_json));
```

Caso os dados venham em *array* apenas passe o parâmetro dentro do `dd()`:

`dd($seu_array);`

**resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma poderá minimizar e maximizar as informações na tela

Comment: Boa! A minha opção não faz isso, apenas "printa" de forma organizada.

Comment: Ajuda pra caramba na ora de debugar

Comment: Muito boa essa opcao e era o que eu estava procurando. No projeto que eu estou trabalhando agora nao é Laravel. Como vai funcionar isso?

Comment: Este pacote não depende do _laravel_. Ele foi extraído. Você pode fazer um teste, criar um projeto, instalar o pacote via _composer_, atribuir o `autoload.php` na página, criar um array e aplicar um `dd($array)` como teste.

Answer (score 5):

Se estiver usando uma versão do PHP que seja 5.4+, você pode usar a constante **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT** do método *json_econde()*. Segue exemplo:

```
$a = ['cor'=> 'azul', 'largura' => '120', 'modelo' => 'A'];
echo json_encode($a, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Mais informações em: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php